# Compilation error in basic Fortran do loop

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am sure I am missing something really basic here, but I am wondering why this *"for"* loop does not work.

```
program main

    implicit none

    integer                         :: index
    integer,dimension(10000)        :: array

    write(*,*) lbound(array)
    write(*,*) ubound(array)    

    do index = lbound(array), ubound(array)
        write(*,*) array(index)
    end do

end program
```

This is the compilation error:

```sh
$ /usr/local/bin/gfortran8 -mcmodel=medium -fcheck=all -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc8 -o test test.f90
test.f90:9:11:

  do index = lbound(array), ubound(array)
           1
Error: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be a scalar
$
```

I am using gfortran (gcc8) and Fortran90 standard.

Comment: lbound and ubound without the Dim optional argument return an arrays - hence your error. Try lbound( array, Dim = 1 ) and similar for ubound. There are similar questions here - this is probably effectively a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks I get it now